# API returning JSON with DataType format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

Not sure if am correct. For Getting Data from API we make AJAX calls from Jquery and API return  data  as JSON like below

```
[ { "Name":"Test1","check":"true","data":"2"},
  { "Name":"Test2","check":"true","data":"3.1"},
  { "Name":"Test3","check":"false","data":"100"}]
```

How can i get in the below format

```
  [ { "Name":"Test1","check":true,"data":2},
      { "Name":"Test2","check":true,"data":3.1},
      { "Name":"Test3","check":false,"data":100}]
```

Am doing some logic in the Client side where my operation will be simple if i get same data in below format

How can i get the data without adding Quotes(")  to all  types

```
"2" should be 2 -- Number
"true" should be true - Boolean
```

What is the generic and easiest way  to achieve this?

Update:

In C#  already my properties are with correct data type like Boolean,decimal

Thanks

Comment: why not cast to a boolean or number in the code?

Comment: `check` must be boolean in c# code: `public bool check {get; set;}` and `data` can be decimal: `public decimal data {get; set;}`.

Comment: Btw, actually, your json data is invalid. The `data` key needs to be in double quoted. `"data":2`.

Comment: Updated JSON and my C# already have correct data types but when it reaches client it is getting lost

Comment: Please post the C# class representing the response object and the code that handles the API call. We have dozens of Web API endpoints and they do not quote every value. Also check to ensure you don't have code in your start-up that is configuring JSON .NET to quote everything.

Comment: @CraigW. am from jquery ajax and how  do i set endpoint to make this scenario work

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, please post the C# class representing the response object and the .NET code that creates the response.